When Mr. Incredible saved a man from killing himself, is he really liable for damages?
If you're not familiar with The Incredibles, at the start, a man falls off a skyscraper (intending to commit suicide), and Mr. Incredible jumps off another roof-top and catches him, stopping him from dying (but he seemingly suffers a broken neck injury). For convenience, let's call the suicidal man Sam (and Mr. Incredible's name is Bob).
Afterwards, a huge litigation happens and Sam's lawyer said that Sam didn't want to be saved and that Mr. Incredible left him in a horrible state. Relevant video clip: https://youtu.be/oXAYWk7Jgbc?t=58

Aside from the fact that super-heroes aren't real, does Sam have a case here? If someone stops you from dying and leaves you in a horrible state in the process, do you have grounds to take legal action against them? A realistic example I can think of is that one attempts suicide with extreme methods (cutting, etc), but doctors are called to save the patient without the patient's consent, and the patient now has to live on in a very compromised state instead of being dead.

Is it worth noting that the scene in question takes place in 1947? I wouldn't be surprised if many of the relevant laws have changed since then.

Aside from the fact that super-heroes aren't real [citation needed]

It wasn’t clear to me when watching the movie that the man’s neck was broken. Maybe strained, but he was jerking his head about in a way that suggested to me that his court appearance was dressed up a little to prejudice the court — i.e. “Sam” and his lawyers were being scuzzy and looking for an easy payout (and reiterated by the jury all wearing neck braces to emphasize that they believed it).

@Dúthomhas that wasn't the jury, those were the plaintiffs in the train crash suit.

I don't think the injury depicted is a broken neck at all. The foam brace shown around the plaintiff's neck is assumed to indicate whiplash, which is a strain of the neck muscles. A broken neck is the common term for fractured cervical vertebra(e), which is a far more serious condition than whiplash.

Re history and laws, laws are a second line of defense for when culture fails. If there's no statutory excuse defense in 1947 for such acts, and there was a statutory defense law later, it's probably not because there was no such excuse defense in 1947, but because that excuse defense could be assumed to work every single time without the need for a statute.

"The plaintiff, Oliver Sansweet..."

If superheroes were real, there would probably have been a law enacted to address that reality.

@MJD Yeah... I knew I was probably getting that part wrong... I should have watched the clip again first before typing... Thanks!

Isn't there a legal principle (pre-Good Samaritan laws) that an action by A can result in involuntary behavior by B and that therefore A is responsible for the consequences? I mean, a superhero would reflexively save people, it's what they do.

@MJD: It is very relevant. The typical fan theories around this film mention FTCA, effective in 1946, which allows private parties to sue the federal government for various torts.

@ToddWilcox there are broken necks and broken necks. A relative had a fall and wore a surgical collar off and on. Only after a couple of years did they discover a neck vertebra had been broken, and had fused together in a misaligned position, irritating the spinal column. Aside: the surgeon who offered to break it and reset it was the same one who accidentally severed the person's thumb nerve a few years earlier, so "No, thank you."

@ohwilleke Statutory law as is, in general, already touches on that. For Mr. Incredible, his actions were alleged to fall within the domain of existent statutory law for him to be prosecuted relative to existent statutory law. For someone like The Flash, it might be argued he has to follow traffic laws. For someone like Superman flying about, air traffic laws, Someone with nuclear powers? Nuclear laws... and so on and so forth.

@DennisFrancisBlewett The point isn't that there aren't laws that accidentally would impact superheroes which were designed for different purposes. The point is that new laws would be enacted that are better suited to the new reality.

No
In the United States all 50 states have a version of the Good Samaritan Law that provides legal protection to people who give reasonable assistance to those who are, or whom they believe to be injured, ill, in peril, or otherwise incapacitated.
New York specifically has several statutes covering Good Samaritan laws.
"NY CLS Pub Health § 3000-a (2009) § 3000-a.  Emergency medical treatment" covers people in general.


Except as provided in subdivision six of section six thousand six hundred eleven, subdivision two of section six thousand five hundred twenty-seven, subdivision one of section six thousand nine hundred nine and sections six thousand five hundred forty-seven and six thousand seven hundred thirty-seven of the education law, any person who voluntarily and without expectation of monetary compensation renders first aid or emergency treatment at the scene of an accident or other emergency outside a hospital, doctor’s office or any other place having proper and necessary medical equipment, to a person who is unconscious, ill, or injured, shall not be liable for damages for injuries alleged to have been sustained by such person or for damages for the death of such person alleged to have occurred by reason of an act or omission in the rendering of such emergency treatment unless it is established that such injuries were or such death was caused by gross negligence on the part of such person. Nothing in this section shall be deemed or construed to relieve a licensed physician, dentist, nurse, physical therapist or registered physician’s assistant from liability for damages for injuries or death caused by an act or omission on the part of such person while rendering professional services in the normal and ordinary course of his or her practice.
(i) A person who, or entity, partnership, corporation, firm or society that, purchases or makes available resuscitation equipment that facilitates first aid, [fig 1] an automated external defibrillator or an epinephrine auto-injector device [fig 2] as required by or pursuant to law or local law, or (ii) [fig 3] an emergency health care provider [fig 4] under a collaborative agreement [fig 5] pursuant to section three thousand-b of this article with respect to an automated external defibrillator, [fig 6] or (iii) the emergency health care provider with a collaborative agreement under section three thousand-c of this article with respect to use of an epinephrine auto-injector device, [fig 7] shall not be liable for damages arising either from the use of that equipment by a person who voluntarily and without expectation of monetary compensation renders first aid or emergency treatment at the scene of an accident or medical emergency, or from the use of defectively manufactured equipment; provided that this subdivision shall not limit the person’s or entity’s, partnership’s, corporation’s, firm’s society’s or the emergency health care provider’s liability for his, her or its own negligence, gross negligence or intentional misconduct.


Some countries even have a duty to rescue which takes this further to the point where a person can be held liable for failing to come to the rescue of another party who could face potential injury or death without being rescued.
Historically
MJD has pointed out that the scene in question happened in 1947.
The first Good Samaritan statute was passed in 1959 in California.
New York has had one since at least September 2014, but that's as far back as the NYS website goes.
Trained professionals
BOCCASILE v. CAJUN MUSIC LIMITED (1997) shows that volunteers are covered by Good Samaritan Laws at least in Rhode Island.
New York has several statutes covering professionals including "§ 6547.  Emergency services rendered by physician assistant"

Notwithstanding any inconsistent provision of any general, special or local law, any physician assistant properly registered in this state who voluntarily and without the expectation of monetary compensation renders first aid or emergency treatment at the scene of an accident or other emergency, outside a hospital, doctor’s office or any other place having proper and necessary medical equipment, to a person who is unconscious, ill or injured, shall not be liable for damages for injuries alleged to have been sustained by such person or for damages for the death of such person alleged to have occurred by reason of an act or omission in the rendering of such first aid or emergency treatment unless it is established that such injuries were or such death was caused by gross negligence on the part of such physician assistant. Nothing in this section shall be deemed or construed to relieve a licensed physician assistant from liability for damages for injuries or death caused by an act or omission on the part of a physician assistant while rendering professional services in the normal and ordinary course of his practice.

Again this doesn't specifically cover preventative action.

That can't be the real law. What kind of crazy people spell out section numbers like that, instead of writing them numerically? :)

More seriously, where does it say "in peril"? It says "unconscious, ill, or injured". That allows the good samaritan to take action after an accident, but it doesn't seem to include preventative action.

@Barmar you're correct that the definition I used is more comprehensive than what's in the NY statute. However there's nothing in it that disagrees with that definition. So from the statutes it does have and reading some of the other states statutes I believe you would be covered in NY

@Barmar see the New York (state) Senate https://www.nysenate.gov/legislation/laws/PBH/3000-A for "Except as provided in
subdivision six of section six thousand six hundred eleven, subdivision
two of section six thousand five hundred twenty-seven, subdivision one
of section six thousand nine hundred nine and sections six thousand five
hundred forty-seven and six thousand seven hundred thirty-seven of the
education law, ..."

@Henry It was sarcasm....

@Barmar ITYM "9th letter of alphabet, 20th letter of alphabet, space, 23rd level of alphabet, 1st letter of alphabet, 19th letter of alphabet, space, 19th letter of alphabet, 1st letter of alphabet, 18th letter of alphabet, 3rd letter of alphabet, 1st letter of alphabet 19th letter of alphabet, 13th letter of alphabet..."

There's a problem: Good Samaritan Laws almost always exclude people who are trained and/or paid. They would not cover a doctor or a firefighter who should have insurance. Mr. Incredible, at the time of the incident, was a government-sanctioned superhero, thus they and/or their employer would still be liable.

@user71659 I can't find it now but something I read yesterday said that they typically had to be paid AND have given medical help previously (e.g. the persons own doctor). BOCCASILE v. CAJUN MUSIC LIMITED (1997) demonstrates that volunteer medics are covered by it

@SamDean That doesn't seem likely. This means that doctors are effectively indemnified if something goes wrong the first time they treat you. If you go to the ER or Urgent Care, you're not likely to be seen by someone who has previously given you medical help. If I read that decision correctly, they said that the plaintiff didn't provide any evidence of a "standard of care" that the medics failed to meet; nothing to do with them being volunteers.

@Barmar everything I've read so far includes wording like "outside a hospital, doctor’s office or any other place having proper and necessary medical equipment", which is what I've been referring to. Sorry if that wasn't clear.
This analysis says it was a Good Samaritan law that covered them "Supreme Court of Rhode Island held that a physician and nurse, who volunteered their services at a music festival, were covered by the state's Good Samaritan statutes"

@Yakk You're going to have to specify which alphabet you use, in each instance. For example Å is the 27th letter of the Swedish alphabet but the 29th of the Norwegian (and Danish) alphabet.

@user3445853 Oh, no worries!  This is the just the bog-standard* Latin alphabet.  Specifically the ancient one.  ...So, missing several letters.  ...Also it's in Dvorak, for some reason, which means that somehow we need to convert from a two-dimensional layout to a one-dimensional layout.  And they all have diacritics, but only the wrong ones.  (*Well, for some people.  Specifically, it's the one that was standard for people who lived in bogs?)

I will assess this under negligence because you have been vague about what cause of action might exist.
On the facts that you've presented, even taking them all as true, Mr. Incredible has not breached any standard of care that could plausibly be attributed to him. Without a breach of any standard of care, there is no negligence claim. Further, the "horrible state" was not caused by Mr. Incredible in the hypothetical you described.
The only way someone may attract liability for a rescue is if they execute the rescue negligently, but this is not even a universal approach.

You could argue that there was a breach in that you can expect a rescue not to cause physical injury. Since the rescue itself caused the injury, you could maybe argue for negligence there? The horrible state was caused by Mr. Incredible: by catching the plaintiff who was at the time travelling at high speed towards the ground, Mr Incredible caused the injury.

@terdon Rescues can absolutely cause injury; airbags are probably the classic example. Fall arrest lanyards are also known for pretty severe jerk when they catch you. I expect that to say causing injury was negligent you'd have to show (at minimum) that the rescue could have been performed under the same circumstances without causing the injury, and that it was a specific way the rescue was carried out (not sheer chance) that caused the injury.

Yes, @SomeoneSomewhereSupportsMonica, exactly. This is presumably what would have been litigated in the movie. The negligence (or absence, thereof) is what the court case would have been about. This answer states that i) there is no standard of care, and I think there is ("you could have saved him without breaking his neck if you were more careful) and ii) that Mr. Incredible didn't cause the injury, but he did.

@terdon standard of care is always expressed in terms of the expected quality of action, not in terms of absense of harm, otherwise it would simply duplicate the separate "harm" element of negligence. Simply causing harm is never also the breach of the standard. Negligence treats the two separately. I did not say there is no standard of care, I said the facts do not establish that he breached any plausible standard of care. And the answer does not assert that Mr Incredible caused the injury. If it meant that, it should have said that.

You wrote "Mr. Incredible has not breached any standard of care that could plausibly be attributed to him", but what do you base this on? From my ignorance, it seems that "take all possible measures to avoid causing injury" is a plausible standard of care which may have been breached. Why are you saying otherwise? And no, the answer doesn't assert that Mr I. caused the injury, it asserts that Mr I did not cause it, but I don't understand why since it seems quite obvious that he did cause it.

@terdon that is such a high standard of care I can confidently say it would not be imposed by a court. If you have any case where a court required all possible measures rather than all reasonable measures, please show me. It is also not obvious from the Q that Mr. incredible caused the injury. It says he attempted a rescue, and instead of death, Sam "seemingly suffers a broken neck injury" — without attributing that broken neck to Mr Incredible. Very possible that Mr. incredible barely saved Sam from dying, but Sam still hit the ground enough to break his neck, caused by Sam.

Oh no, I don't know the first thing about this, let alone have an example! I am trying to understand here, not challenge. Please imagine I had written "all reasonable measures" there, I am as far from a lawyer as it gets. I just don't understand the claims you are making here and was hoping you would edit to clarify and explain. If you watch the clip, by the way, it seems quite obvious that Mr I caused the injury by barreling into the falling guy.

Got it. Well, you seemed very confident. I will return later to add to the answer to explain these distinctions a little more carefully. It does skip over some reasoning. I'm not watching a clip though — if the question wants to include a fact, it needs to say it.

Fair enough, I share your aversion to requiring folks to go watch a video. I did see it in this case cause I love the movie and it was only ~10 seconds. My apologies if I came across as confident, mine were honest questions, they were not intended as assertions.

"I will assess this under negligence because you have been vague about what cause of action might exist." well, the movie was too. Also, that's part of the question.

"The only way someone may attract liability for a rescue is if they execute the rescue negligently, but this is not even a universal approach." That might be a really good answer to this if the idea of the courts were thrown out, such as an extrajudicial prosecution were taken toward Sam. In that it were a fact that Sam behaved ideally as a reasonable person ought to have, then Sam need not deal with any prosecution (court/extrajudicial/etc.).

Question: When Mr. Incredible saved a man from killing himself, is he really liable for damages?
Answer: No (relative to the perspective of prosecution in civil court, for which you expand upon in your question) because damages could only be received from a process of fraud upon the court having occurred (such as in development of the case and the persistence of its prosecution).
See also: Federal Rules of Evidence Rule 104.

The question is about  a civil lawsuit, not criminal prosecution.

@Barmar What aspect of my response made you think that I was referring to criminal prosecution? I was not referring to criminal prosecution. I was referring to prosecution in civil court.

I wasn't aware there's any other kind of prosecution.
